# Calculate walking times across route

Tags: networkx, osmnx

I am trying to calculate travel distances across a walkable street network I've downloaded using `OSMNX`. I have generated a route from an origin to a destination using `NetworkX`'s `nx.shortest_path` function. However, whenever I calculate my route setting "travel_time" as weight, I get inaccurate results. I was wondering if this might have to do with the "speed_kph" attribute in the network. Is there a way to manually set speeds to equate walking speeds (e.g. 5 kph?)?

Comment: Hello, it would be helpful to have an example of an inaccurate result... (to understand where the error might be coming from).

Comment: Hi, yes, I think you might be able to access a sample code via this link: https://github.com/cpeiret/walking_times/blob/main/walking_distances.ipynb

I've checked the walking times using Google Maps and they differ significantly.

Comment: Could you include in your question a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Then we can check if these differences are from any issue with the algorithm or simply that google maps uses different data

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `nx.shortest_path_length` function and the `travel_time` attribute. Note the `travel_time` attribute is not present by default in your graph. In order to add it you need to use [`ox.add_edge_travel_times`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.speed.add_edge_travel_times).

The Networkx function [shortest_path_length](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length.html) states in it's documentation:

> **weight** -
> If None, every edge has weight/distance/cost 1. If a string, use this edge attribute as the edge weight. Any edge attribute not present defaults to 1.

Since the `travel_time` is not present you get the shortest path which has the minimum edges.

This can be verified by trying:

```
weight = nx.shortest_path_length(walk_network, origin_nn, destination_nn, weight = 'fake_key')
```

---

Since usually in walking you assume a constant speed, a possible solution would be to use the edge `length` and calculate the speed separately.

For example:

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

WALKING_SPEED = 1.4 # m/s average walkihg speed

walk_network = ox.graph.graph_from_address('Piccadilly Circus, London', dist = 1000, network_type = 'walk')


origin = (-0.13492669985021463, 51.51016491413415)
destination = (-0.12516, 51.51112)

origin_nn = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(walk_network, origin[0], origin[1])
destination_nn = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(walk_network, destination[0], destination[1])


length = nx.shortest_path_length(walk_network, origin_nn, destination_nn, weight = 'length')
duration = length / WALKING_SPEED / 60
print('The shortest walking route is {:.2f} meters and will take {:.2f} minutes'.format(length, duration))
```